# G1 does not allow to allocate large object while Parallel does

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot, g1gc

`openjdk 11.0.14.1 2022-02-08`

Consider the following simple Java program.

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
    int i[] = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2];
}
```

Here `int` is 4 byte in size so allocating `int[Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2]` requires `4G` of free heap size. Now let's run the program with different options.

**I.** `-XX:+UseParallelGC -Xmx5g`

**Result**: Crash with `OutOfMemoryError`.

Even in spite of the fact that heap size is large enough. It's clear since the `-XX:NewSize` is `1310 MB` by default and the Old generation is not large enough.

**II.** `-XX:+UseParallelGC -Xmx5g -XX:MaxNewSize=128m -XX:NewSize=128m`

**Result:** Completed normally

The application runs fine since the Old generation is large enough to hold the array allocation.

Now let's change the collector from `Parallel` to `G1`

**III.** `-XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx5g -XX:MaxNewSize=128m -XX:NewSize=128m`

**Result:** Crash with `OutOfMemoryError`.

And this is what I have no idea about. I thought that adjusting `-XX:G1HeapWastePercent` would help, but it didn't.

Why can't `G1` hold the allocation of the array and what options to adjust in order to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried a newer JDK? Doesn't seem to be an issue in the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a JVM bug [JDK-8279241](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8279241) "G1 Full GC does not always slide memory to bottom addresses". It should be resolved in JDK 19.

The workaround is to disable Class Data Sharing. The test does not fail with `-Xshare:off`